# How to get unique records off a MySql Table

Tags: mysql

I have a mysql table with the following fields."Image id, date, media_name, media_type, rate, value, Sector, Category, Customer & Product". The table contains about 5 mil records. There are multiple records for each media-id. We would like to extract the first record of each media_id that was copied in the table. First record basically means we are copying the data off just one record, for each specific image_id, using the date field. To illustrate this more clearly please take a look at the Data screenshot in the link below. In the screenshot you can see a sample of 5 records from the original data table which contains 5 mil records. Below these records, you can see the actual result of the query, being two records.
We tried several queries but we always end up getting multiple records of the same image_id. Any ideas anyone?

[image: Data Screenshot]

Comment: Please see: [Why should I provide an MCRE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Answer (score 0):

If MySQL 8, you can use row_number function with over clause.
The query to extract the first record(ord=1) of each image_id order by date is below:

```
select * from
  (select *,
   row_number() over(partition by image_id order by date) as ord from Original_Table) a
where ord=1
```

However, I'm not sure that you will get enough performance in case of 5mil records.